# Why can't I open the hyperlink

Tags: html

I can not open the hyperlink of "elixirs" and "detailed directions", I do not why ,they are all in a file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Head First Lounge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the New and Improved Head First Lounge</h1>
    <img src="drinks.gif">
    <p>
       Join us any evening for refreshing <a href=“elixir.html”>elixirs</a>,
       conversation and maybe a game or two of 
       <em>Dance Dance Revolution</em>.
       Wireless access is always provided;  
       BYOWS (Bring your own web server).
    </p>
    <h2>Directions</h2>
    <p>
      You'll find us right in the center of downtown Webville.   
      If you need help finding us, check out our <a href = “directions.html”>detailed directions</a>.
      Come join us!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use the incorrect quotes. Use `"` instead of `“`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put single quotes `'` on every `href`

try this

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Head First Lounge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the New and Improved Head First Lounge</h1>
    <img src='drinks.gif'>
    <p>
       Join us any evening for refreshing <a href='elixir.html'>elixirs</a>,
       conversation and maybe a game or two of 
       <em>Dance Dance Revolution</em>.
       Wireless access is always provided;  
       BYOWS (Bring your own web server).
    </p>
    <h2>Directions</h2>
    <p>
      You'll find us right in the center of downtown Webville.   
      If you need help finding us, check out our <a href = 'directions.html'>detailed directions</a>.
      Come join us!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```